# How do I access data in GraphQL if not by the id?

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-js

I'm using GraphQL with Meteor and [Pup v2](https://cleverbeagle.com/pup/v2/graphql/pupql), and I have a problem accessing the users data via a special ID provided to every user on signup, this ID will be used in a link (mysite.com/user/specialId) so other users can view the searched users account. Problem is, I can't get the data with the special ID, I can't get any data back if I don't pass in the users _id provided by MongoDB. Below I have a bunch of the code used:

### Attempt 1

I tried to use a custom on-the-go way just to be able to at least access the data to see if it works (and then implement it correctly later)

```
const GET_USER_DETAILS = gql`
  query user($userId: String) {
  user(userId: $userId) {
    userId
    username
    _id
  }
}
`;
```

Here I export so I can get the data:

```
export default compose(
     graphql(GET_USER_DETAILS, {
        options: ({ match }) => ({
          fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
          variables: {
            // existing specialId for testing purposes, to be replaced with match.params.userId
            userId: "J4xZzvvhBDSEufnBn",
          },
        }),
      }),
)(PublicProfileView);
```

This returns a 400 error `Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400 error` and after multiple attempts, I could not fix it, so I tried a different approach...

### Attempt 2

I tried to go deep into the files and change the GraphQL. Created a new query:

```
query userById($userId: String) {
  userById(userId: $userId) {
    ...UserAttributes
  }
}
```

(Mentioned fragment)

```
fragment UserAttributes on User {
  _id
  name {
    ... 
  }
  username
  emailAddress
  oAuthProvider
  roles {
    ...
  }
  settings {
   ...
  }
  userId
}
```

Tried to add new item in API:

```
type Query {
   ...
   userById(userId: String): User
   ...
}
```

Resolver:

```
resolvers: {
  Query: {
    ...
    userById: (parent, args) => {
      // Assuming args equals an object like { _id: '123' };
      return UserQueries.userById(args);
    },
  },
},
```

query.js, attempt 1:

```
userById: (parent) => queryUsers.find({ userId: parent.userId }, { sort: { createdAt: 1 } }).fetch()
```

Attempt 2:

```
userById: (parent, args, context) => {
  return queryUsers({
    
    userId: parent.userId,
  });
},
```

And finally

### Attempt 3

I tried to modify the get query

```
const getQueryModified = (options) => {
  // console.log(options.userId)
  try {
    return options.userId
      ? { 'userId': options.userId }
      : { userId: options.userId };
  } catch (exception) {
    throw new Error(`[queryUsers.getQuery] ${exception.message}`);
  }
};
```

Here is the original query I tried to modify:

```
const getQuery = (options) => {
  try {
    return options.search
      ? {
          _id: { $ne: options.currentUser._id },
          $or: [
            { 'profile.name.first': options.search },
            { 'profile.name.last': options.search },
            { 'emails.address': options.search },
            // { 'userId': options.search },
            { 'services.facebook.first_name': options.search },
            { 'services.facebook.last_name': options.search },
            { 'services.facebook.email': options.search },
          ],
        }
      : { _id: options.currentUser._id };
  } catch (exception) {
    throw new Error(`[queryUsers.getQuery] ${exception.message}`);
  }
};
```

Unfortunately this was also unsuccessful, the best I get from these when executing the below query is null...

```
userById(userId: "J4xZzvvhBDSEufnBn"){
  username
}
```

All I want is to **get the user data from their userId and not their _id**, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it

Comment: follow some [more datailed] tutorial about BE/server only and play with playground before any client coding ... your resolvers doesn't return user object, console log result before return